# Function resolution

Tags: c++, templates, function, macros

I have a lot of functions with this signature:

```
DoSomething(int x, int y, int z, int t, int u, int p);
```

They all have the same number of parameters and the same type of parameters.

I want to be able to use them like this:

```
DoSomething(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

I know the compiler cannot distinguish between functions of the same signature (they are plain illegal).

To that affect I would like to wrap the parameters of the functions in logical "Constructs". This does not mean classes or structures. For example:

```
DoSomething(Construct1(x, y, z), Construct2(t, u, p));
or
DoSomething(Construct1(x, y), Constrcut2(t, u, p, o));
```

In this case I can distinguish between the two functions and they have the same number of parameters. If I use objects with different constructors even if it is const by ref, using a class or a structure, the Construct is still created. For Example:

```
DoSomething(const Construct1& constr1, const Construct2& constr2)
{
    constr1.x + constr2.t
}
DoSomething(Construct1(1, 2, 3), Construct2(4, 5, 6));
```

In this case Construct1 and Construct2 are both created.

What I want is:

```
DoSomething(Construct1(x, y, z), Construct2(t, u, p));
or
DoSomething(Construct1(x, y), Constrcut2(t, u, p, o));
```

at compile time to expand to:

```
DoSomething(int x, int y, int z, int t, int u, int p);
```

thus eliminating the need for the object creation. I am not looking for an object solution. Anything that can expand this is welcome. Even if it is a macro. I am not looking for a complete solution, but if you can point me to what I should read in order to make this myself then that is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two `y`s in your parameter lists.

Comment: What do you mean by, "I do not want to read values from a file with millions of lines"?

Answer (score 4):

Overloading is based on the parameter *types* rather than the parameter *names*. You cannot have overloaded functions which have parameter lists with identical types.

Comment: Those names were there just to iterate that both functions have the same number and type of parameters but do different things.

Comment: I can't really understand what your problem is. The commments have left me rather confused. I can't help but feel you are overcomplicating this. Overloading really doesn't look like the right answer to the problem. I'd expect that the best solution involves functions with different names that make it clear to anyone reading the code what they do, and why each function with identical parameter lists is different.

Comment: @user985611 Why can't you use different function names?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a couple of misconceptions. The most obvious is that the names of the parameters matter... they don't, as far as the compiler is concerned those two function declarations declare a single function that takes 6 integers (consider, if they were different, what would `DoSomething( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )` do?)

The second misconception is that an object creation necessarily means an allocation. In the code you presented: `DoSomething( Object1(x,y,z), Object2(t,y,u) )` there are two objects but not a single dynamic allocation (unless you do them inside `Object1` or `Object2` constructors).

Overall you should write code that is readable, and only if that **proves** to be slow, then **profile** and try to optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: @user985611: you do understand that the cost of creating those objects is almost nothing, and you are looking for a way to force changes in the code that will make it harder to understand just to circumvent a problem that does not exist?

Comment: I do not need anyone else to understand the code. Unless you have a solution please refrain from posting just for the sake of posting. If I am asking it means that I need it.

Comment: What you ask is hard to accomplish and the code you will produce will be hard to maintain. The reasons you provided in your question are either unclear or are simply not true: "to avoid unnecessary memory allocations" - that will -not- happen. "use x, y, z, t, y, u without going through Object1 and Object2" - in typical situations the compiler will do exactly that under the hood! Compilers are smart enough to optimise the code out. However, you mention some lines in a file, are you trying to somehow serialize those functions (or function calls) in a file, or something?

Comment: Those reasons were just examples. I just want to know how I can make the compiler distinguish between two identical functions without using classes or anything that needs to be created at runtime.

Comment: @user985611: You should take an open approach to learning. You have decided to read the answer as a rant against your approach, fine, but note that the approach in the accepted answer will in many cases be worse than the original version with things *that need to be created at runtime*. If you want to know why, you will need to find out what happens when a `const` reference is bound to a temporary. As I already mentioned in the answer, that is one of your misconceptions. Good luck.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But I have a specific situation and I want to use something like "DoSomething(Object1, Object2) without creating the temporary objects. Const to ref still creates them: DoSomething(const Object1 &obj1, const Object2 &obj2). DoSomething(Object1(1, 2, 3), Object2(4, 5, 6)) and in this situation still the temporary objects are created.

Comment: @user985611: What is exactly the problem of creating those objects? What is the reason that drives you not to create them? What I am not sure at all is that you or I understand what the implications of creating those objects are. So, again, the question which is simple: Why do you want to avoid creating those temporaries?

Comment: I find that object creation pointless. I am not really looking for an object solution. Anything that can expand this: DoSomething(Construct1(x, y, z), Construct2(t, y, u)) into DoSomething(x, y, z, t, y, u) is welcome. No matter how strange it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you'll have to find some other route. The compiler ignores any names you give to parameters in a function declaration, so as far as it cares, what you have is:

```
DoSomething(int, int, int, int, int, int);

DoSomething(int, int, int, int, int, int);
```

Since there's no difference between these, you aren't declaring two overloaded functions at all -- you're just declaring the same function twice. Attempting to define two functions with that identical signature then violates the one-definition rule.

Edit: Oh, I suppose I should add that without a return type, those aren't allowable function declarations either (not that it's related to the question at hand, but just in case somebody decides to get pedantic about it -- though I can hardly imagine a C++ programmer doing anything like that).

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid unneeded copies by having Object1 and Object2 expose the underlying storage ints

```
struct Object1 {
...
int x;
int y;
...

}

//<--- passed by reference, no copy happens --->
DoSomething( const Object1& o1, const Object2& o2 ) 
{
  int somethingUseful = o1.x * o2.w - o1.y * o2.z;
}
```

Please elaborate if you still feel there are copies happening with this approach that are not really needed.

Comment: Probably the best way to do it fast and still "clean". Everything else is short of doing direct memory manipulation, ie. memcopy. ;-) You might consider not making your refs const, though (for this special case).

Comment: @Robin, the refs have to be const for the use case OP describes. Temporaries can only bind to const refs, never to non-const refs.

Comment: @Rob, yes... and no. ;-) I meant the getters, ie. `int& getX() const;` You're perfectly right about o1 and o2, of course, so thank you for your clarification! Basically, for this usecase, I would simply declare the variables in Object1 and Object2 public and work on them directly, thus avoiding any copy operation of the integers in DoSomething().

Comment: good point, just removed the getters and made clear you can just copy the contents from the objects

Comment: Gotcha. That makes perfect sense. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Will the object be created? If it is will there be any overhead, no mater how insignificant, compared to simply storing the x and y in a non-class form?

Comment: If it would have been 1970, i would have suggested you to append a `register` keyword to the member declarations to hint the compiler, but this is 2011 and compilers can allocate registers very efficiently.  Btw, if you think this is the right answer, feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: For temporaries this has a higher overhead than the plain *by-copy* approach.

Comment: And I am back to the problem of not being able to distinguish between the 2 functions.

Comment: I will remove it if someone provides the solution I am looking for.

Comment: @user985611, if you are dead serious in having a number of functions with the same parameter types and the same names still be distinguished ( a very odd requirement indeed, it would be good if you explained those reasons) by in any case you are left with other choices: a) wrapping the functions in different classes b) wrapping the functions in different namespaces c) wrapping the function in different nested classes inside a single class. Also, you can mix these 3 options at your heart's content

Answer (score 0):

You cannot even define two identical functions in C++, so asking how the compiler can differentiate between the two if hypothetically they *did* exist is pointless.

Then you seem to be asking how to pass objects in without requiring additional allocations. That is done with const references, but even worrying about this seems premature given that you haven't even got your program's structure solidified yet. Write your program first, *then and only then* optimise if it is needed. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: Do not make assumptions of how much I know or what I want to do with this. I asked a question and unless you know the answer there is no point in commenting. I do not want to create the object. Const to ref creates the object.

Comment: Passing by const ref doesn't create anything, but it does require the object exist somewhere, yes. If you don't want to create the object at all, one could ask why you have a function signature with those objects in it. There is no way to get around the object creation if you place the objects in your function signature, though the optimiser may inline the calls out and then remove the object creation (assuming it has no side-effects).

Comment: I am not looking for an object solution. Anything that can expand this: DoSomething(Construct1(x, y, z), Construct2(t, y, u)) into DoSomething(x, y, z, t, y, u) is welcome. No matter how strange it might be.

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "expand"? What is stopping you from only using `DoSomething(x, y, z, t, y, u)`? If you don't want an object solution, don't write a function that takes objects.

Comment: I have a lot of those functions and I do not want to use different names. I did not write an object function. As I have stated I want the construct to be there just to help the compiler distinguish between both functions. DoSomething(Construct1(1, 2, 3), Construct2(4, 5, 6)) is pointless to create the object just to be able to choose between multiple functions with the same type and number of parameters. I do not care if it is pointless to worry about it or not.

Comment: I'm not saying the problem you're trying to solve is pointless, and I'm sorry if that's how it sounded. The point is, C++ just plain doesn't allow you to define two functions with the same signature, so there could never exist a situation where you need to help the compiler distinguish between them. I'm honestly trying to help (else I wouldn't be writing comments), but I'm finding it very hard to get a sense of what you're actually trying to accomplish here. Could you edit your question with some actual sample code of how you're trying to *use* these functions?